# Get a Magento product collection without sub-products of configurable products

Tags: configurable-product, collection, model, product-collection

I want to get a list of all products available in my Magento installation. Currently I am using the following call to filter out enabled products and limit the result set to those products which are visible both in catalog and search results:

```
$products = \Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('in' => array(
        \Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH,
        \Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
    )))
    ;
```

As all children of configurable products are stored as regular products they show up in the resulting collection. However, I don't want them to be included. Is there any way to safely achieve this?

In case you wonder about all these backslashes: My code runs in an PHP-5.3 compatible environment using namespaces so I had to refer to the global namespace when calling Magento functions.

Thanks in advance,

**Edit** (further explanation of what I want to achieve):

My employer develops an own eCommerce system. This software provides a mechanism similar to Magento's configurable products. All sub-products assigned to a configurable product know about their parent (indicated by the parent's primary key). Hence, it it easy to filter them out by excluding product rows having a non-zero parent ID.

*How is this realized in Magento?* Don't the sub products know which configurable product they are assigned to?

Comment: You can try this: ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE); to get only simple products and ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array( 'neq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out by myself. The table `catalog_product_relation` contains information about parent-child relationships for configurable products. I just had to join the table to my collection and look for product records that do not have a corresponding row in `catalog_product_relation` with their `entity_id` as `child_id`. Quite simple if you know what you have to do.

```
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->joinTable('catalog/product_relation', 'child_id=entity_id', array(
            'parent_id' => 'parent_id'
        ), null, 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
            array(
                'attribute' => 'parent_id',
                'null' => null
            )
        ));
```

Comment: thanks for coming back and posting this, i found it very useful

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array(
        'neq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE))
```

See /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Api2/Product/Rest.php

```
/**
 * Retrieve list of products
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function _retrieveCollection()
{

  ....
  ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array(
        'neq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE))
```

See [Magento SQL query: Get all simple products that are “not visible individually”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862099/magento-sql-query-get-all-simple-products-that-are-not-visible-individually)

Comment: This solution was proposed several times but relies on the products' visibility being set to "not visible individually". Is this the only way in which Magento is able to tell configurable children from regular products apart?

It would be quite awkward to run through all children and check whether they are correctly set to invisible or just aren't assigned to a category and therefore don't show up.