# Get product collection only for "parent Products and Catalog Search visibility" products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-collection, collection-filtering, programmatically

I am working on product collection, my requirement is display only parent Products and Catalog Search visibility products only.

```
$collection = mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->joinTable('catalog/product_relation', 'child_id=entity_id', array(
            'parent_id' => 'parent_id'
        ), null, 'left')->addAttributeToFilter(array(
            array(
                'attribute' => 'parent_id',
                'null' => null
            )
        ));
$visibility = array(
                Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                );

               $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility);
```

But this is not giving correct result of product collection.My all products which are present in both cases are not display in my collection.

Comment: try this http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/32125/18722

Comment: I am using same example for filter parent products only this is working but when i use visibility filter then my other records also not display.

Comment: In collection u want parent products which gives all type of products except associated products

Comment: I want all products but don't want any child product and "Not Visible Individually" products.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
$collection->joinTable('catalog/product_relation', 'child_id=entity_id', array(
            'parent_id' => 'parent_id'
        ), null, 'left')->addAttributeToFilter(array(
            array(
                'attribute' => 'parent_id',
                'null' => null
            )
        ));
```

Comment: This is also not working and gives incorrect records.

Comment: This gives "Not Visible Individually" products also display.

Comment: i am just tested this is working only visible products shown and get correct data

Comment: No this is not giving correct data.

Comment: This is not display all products when apply website filter with stock filter also.